# Invoice doesn't show in Magento Sales > Invoices

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, invoice

When an order is created and handled the invoice is generated. 
The order has his invoice and I can see the invoice at orders > SPECIFIC ORDER > invoices.
However, I can't see this order back in Sales > invoice, the order is completed.

Anybody an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, displaying the company name in the grid caused that only clients with a company field where joined.